# TEventLog does not write to systemlog

Tags: freepascal

I am using Free Pascal (Lazarus) to develop a simple server daemon. The problem I am facing is that the TEventLog component does not write to the systemlog.

I use the following code:

```
  EventLog1.LogType := ltSystem;
  EventLog1.Active := True;
  EventLog1.Log('Application has started!');
```

Instead of writing to systemlog it creates a file with the name as the executable and writes there.
Is there any other way I can write to the system log ? Is `openlog` defined in any unit I can use ?

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you use a *nix and the most recent 2.6.2 version).

No, libc log* functions seem only declared in the implementation of eventlog.  Maybe they are in unit libc, but that is mostly [unsupported](http://wiki.freepascal.org/libc_unit), and linux/32bit only.

Check some assumptions:

1. Is active false before you set logtype, otherwise the active:=true might not recheck it.
2. you want to write system log, do you have enough privileges for that?
3. Do you see anything with strace/ktrace/truss ?